# Хотелось бы получить небольшое код-ревью, т.к. не знаю, как более правильно записать

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, pycharm

хотелось бы получить хоть какой-нибудь фид-бэк о читабельности кода, ошибках и возможных улучшениях. потмоу что даже PyCharm выводит: shadows name ('fill', 'base') from from outer of scope

```
# first_example

def draw_triangle(fill, base):
    for i in range(1, base // 2+2):
        print(fill * i)
    for j in range(base // 2, 0, -1):
        print(fill * j)
    pass


fill = input()
base = int(input())

draw_triangle(fill, base)

# second_example (imho the bestest variant)

def draw_triangle(fill='', base=0):
    for i in range(1, base // 2+2):
        print(fill * i)
    for j in range(base // 2, 0, -1):
        print(fill * j)
    pass


draw_triangle(fill=input(), base=int(input()))
```

Comment: `2+2` лучше писать все же `2 + 2`, а то такое впечатление что `base // 2+2` тут сложение в приоритете;  `pass` в конце функции зачем? `draw_triangle(fill=input(), base=int(input()))` воспринимается сложнее я имею в виду **вызов в вызове**; значения по умолчанию — дело вкуса, иногда очень хорошо когда они есть, все зависит от ситуации

Comment: pass стояло изначально в задаче курса, который я прохожу. я сам не особо понимаю для чего он нужен. в курсе говорилось, что это некая "заглушка"

Comment: насчет читаемости последней строки. в этом случае хоть и страдает читаемость, но за то переменные локальными остаются, в первом же примере - они глобальные. есть ли более красивые способы объявить локальные переменные?

Comment: ну так это не локальные переменные это именованные аргументы, что касается глобальных переменных, я точно знаю что они снижают производительность, поэтому я упаковываю все по возможности в классы

Comment: pass — это команда которая ничего не делает, нужна только когда нечего написать)

Comment: понял, спасибо огромное за фид-бэк)